# Как не закрывать AlertDialog при смене Activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

В коде сначала показываю AlertDialog и сразу же потом запускаю новую активити,и AlertDialog скрывается. Можно ли как-то его не скрывать при старте новой активити?
Попытался сделать это так но все равно не работает

```
class ShowDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DecoderActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Информация")
                .setMessage("QR Code уже считан или неверен")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("ОК",
                        (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alert.show();


        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что если вызвать AlertDialog из сервиса?

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.show();
```

И в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: из сервиса вызываете?

Comment: Если честно не понимаю немного, что такое сервис?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php

Comment: Да что то такое я делал, добавил в ответ детали

Comment: неправильно значит делаете.

Comment: причем здесь asynctask?

Comment: Можете написать как правильно?

Comment: Создаете отдельный класс который наследуется от Service, реализовываете метод onStartCommand и в него уже код который я вам скинул выше, и после этого запускаете сервис там где вам надо методом startService

Comment: @k1crargy к сожалению, я не могу вызывать его в ValueEventListener, но это моя вина, что я не указал это в вопросе поэтому если вы уверены, что в обычном случае код будет работать, я отмечу его как ответ

Answer (score 1):

В голову лезут два вариант:

1. Вызывайте алерт диалог уже из новой активити с соответсвующим контекстом
2. сменяйте активити при закрытии диалога или нажатии на кнопку в нем

А так сделать один диалог, который отображается поверху сначала одной активити, потом другой, скорее всего никак не выйдет. Он же к контексту привязан. Разве что заменить активити на фрагменты, тогда можно

Чтобы сообщить второй активити, что ей надо показать диалог, в первой активити положите в `Intent` сообщение и обработайте его во второй активити

В первой активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("имя переменной", "значение")
startActivity(intent)
```

во второй в onCreate

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("имя переменной");
if(value != null && value.contentEquals("значение"))
    showDialog();
```

Comment: А можно как то отследить, то есть чтобы активити которую я запускаю понимала что я пришел именно оттуда и мне надо показать диалог

Comment: добавил в ответ